# Why does @@RowCount shows 1 row effected but SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns NULL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have the following stored procedure.

```
alter proc uspUpdtStudent
@pStudID int, 
@pTitle char(10),
@pFName varchar(50), 
@pLName varchar(50), 
@pDOB date,
@pGender char(1),
@pIsPriorStud bit, 
@pCitizen varchar(50), 
@pResidency varchar(50), 
@pPic varbinary(max),
--@pOldContact as dbo.Contact readonly, 
@pNewContact as dbo.Contact readonly, 
@pProgTrack tinyint,
@pProgID int,
@pid int output -- why not EnrID? 
as
begin 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @tblNew as table (rw_id int identity(1,1), addL1 varchar(200), sub varchar(100), town varchar(100), post int)

select @pTitle, @pFName, @pLName, @pDOB, @pGender, @pIsPriorStud, @pCitizen, @pResidency, @pPic, @pStudID

    update dbo.Students 
    set 
    Title=@pTitle, 
    FName=@pFName, 
    LName=@pLName, 
    DOB=@pDOB, 
    Gender=@pGender, 
    IsPriorStud=@pIsPriorStud, 
    Citizenship=@pCitizen, 
    Residency=@pResidency, 
    StudImg=@pPic, 
    DateOfRago=GETDATE() 
    where StudID =@pStudID

    select @pStudID as 'Passed Student ID' 

    declare @rowcount int

            set @pid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
            --select @pid

            set @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT

            select @rowcount as 'Effected Row count'    
    if @rowcount > 0
    begin 

        SELECT   @pid as 'Student table row ID'


    end
    else
    begin
        set @pid = -1
        --rollback tran
        return 302
    end


end
go
```

Then i pass theses values to the stored procedure

```
USE [SMSV1]
GO

declare @p13 int
set @p13=-1
declare @p14 dbo.Contact
insert into @p14 values(N'fyyyfyf',N'woeoeoo',N'kokokok',N'123456')

exec uspUpdtStudent @pStudID=100000007,@pTitle=N'Mr.',@pFName=N'George',@pLName=N'kadafi',@pDOB='1940-12-12 00:00:00',@pGender=N'M',@pIsPriorStud=0,@pCitizen=N'LIBIYA',@pResidency=N'LIBIYA',@pPic=null,@pProgID=15,@pProgTrack=2,@pid=@p13 output,@pNewContact=@p14
```

what is funny about is, it adds a row to the student table but when i tried to access the row id from `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` it shows as `NULL`. the IF condition executes because `@@ROWCOUNT` is greater than zero also As you can see in the code i have even saved the id value in a variable `@pid`. I have attached [this video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Py_KatlT2sM&feature=youtu.be) so it might help to understand understand the situation.

Here is my student table

```
USE [SMSV1]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Students]    Script Date: 12/18/2014 07:39:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudID] [int] NULL,
    [Title] [char](10) NULL,
    [FName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DOB] [date] NULL,
    [Gender] [char](1) NULL,
    [IsPriorStud] [bit] NULL,
    [Citizenship] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Residency] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [StudImg] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [DateOfRago] [datetime] NULL,
    [Updt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Students] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Students] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Students_Updt]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Updt]
GO
```

thanks

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (`@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@@ROWCOUNT` gets reset per each statement. Try the following to see:

```
DECLARE @Test INT;
SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 20;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 20;
SET @Test = 1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Returns:

> 10
> 20
>
> 2
>
> 10
> 20
>
> 1 -- this is 1 instead of 2 due to the SET command being between the second two SELECTs

If you want `SET @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT;` to be accurate, it has to be the next statement after the `UPDATE`. Where you currently have it (i.e. after a SET command) `@rowcount` will always be 1 no matter what happens with the `UPDATE`.

Also, there is no `INSERT`, so `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` would have to return `NULL`. And why would you need to dynamically get the ID anyway? Isn't it being passed into the proc via `@pStudID`? If for some reason the `[StudID]` field in the `[Students]` table is not the IDENTITY field, you can still get that via the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause:

```
UPDATE dbo.Students 
SET 
    Title=@pTitle, 
    FName=@pFName, 
    LName=@pLName, 
    DOB=@pDOB, 
    Gender=@pGender, 
    IsPriorStud=@pIsPriorStud, 
    Citizenship=@pCitizen, 
    Residency=@pResidency, 
    StudImg=@pPic, 
    DateOfRago=GETDATE() 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID -- this is the IDENTITY field as per the CREATE TABLE statement
WHERE StudID = @pStudID;
```

Using the `OUTPUT` clause in this manner will result in a 1 row, 1 column result set ONLY IF a row is updated. If there is no matching row, there is no result set. If you want a clearer indication of no row updated than merely no result set, as I mentioned above, put the `SET @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT;` just after the UPDATE and then you can test for `IF (@RowCount = 0)...`.

IF you need the `ID` field in the `@pid` variable since it is an OUTPUT parameter, then you need to capture the result set of the `UPDATE...OUTPUT` into a temp table or table variable:

```
DECLARE @UpdatedID TABLE (ID INT);

UPDATE dbo.Students 
SET 
    Title=@pTitle, 
    FName=@pFName, 
    LName=@pLName, 
    DOB=@pDOB, 
    Gender=@pGender, 
    IsPriorStud=@pIsPriorStud, 
    Citizenship=@pCitizen, 
    Residency=@pResidency, 
    StudImg=@pPic, 
    DateOfRago=GETDATE() 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID -- this is the IDENTITY field as per the CREATE TABLE statement
INTO   @UpdatedID (ID)
WHERE StudID = @pStudID;

SELECT @pid = ID
FROM   @UpdatedID;

IF (@pid IS NULL)
BEGIN
  SET @pid = -1;
  RETURN 302;
END;
```

Comment: as a habit i add an id column for each table in this case studID is the student identity card no, also it has a separate row id column called "id" this id is set with auto increment

Comment: @PhillGreggan What is a row id? Do you mean a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` field marked as `ROWGUIDCOL`? Also, and again, why would you need or want to get the value of the IDENTITY when you are passing it in to begin with?

Comment: row_id is a column that starts from 1 and increments by 1 for each insert e.g.: for student ID 1000000 row_id is 10 and for student ID 10000001 row_id is 11

Comment: Is it a SEQUENCE or something you generate via MAX + 1? You just said that studID is the IDENTITY field and you can only have 1 of those. Maybe post the full CREATE TABLE statement in the question, please?

Comment: @PhillGreggan Thanks. I saw that and have updated my answer to correct the field name in the `OUTPUT` clause. It appears that I was correct in thinking that `StudID` was _not_ the IDENTITY field as that explains why you wanted to dynamically get the ID field associated with `StudID`. And just FYI, when communicating with people about this, please do not say that `StudID` "is the student identity card no" as that implies it is the IDENTITY field, which is merely an issue of multiple meanings of "identity", but is has a very specific meaning in SQL Server which leads to confusion.

Comment: @PhillGreggan Thanks. And I updated the answer again showing a method of capturing the IDENTITY value into the OUTPUT param variable. In that method, you really don't need to capture `@@ROWCOUNT` since the value of `@pid` will either be retrieved from the table variable, or it will be NULL if no row was inserted, in which case it gets changed to -1 in the IF block.

Answer (score 1):

From [SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) (Bold for emphasis mine)

Returns the last identity value **inserted** into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

You are doing an Update, not an insert, hence it is not being set.

Comment: i have used @@ROWIDENTITY before and gave me same results so i have changed it to SCOPE_IDENTITY() before post which also gives the same results and now it doesnt work on updates : )